# IFR requirement for altimeter question (i.e. +/- 75 feet)

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, altimeter

What if the ATIS/AWOS/ASOS results in a very low or very high altimeter setting (i.e. barometric pressure)? Surely this setting will result in an altimeter setting way outside the envelope of the +/- 75 feet related to field elevation? Since each inch of Hg results in 1,000' change...what am I missing w.r.t. the altimeter check?

Comment: What do you mean by "very low or very high"? Inaccurate readings? Values below or above the range of the altimeter? Something else?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Setting your altimeter to the correct local setting will make it more accurate, not less accurate. Can you give a specific example with some numbers?

Answer (score 2):

Barometric pressure isn't a constant. Just because you're at sea level, doesn't mean the air pressure is going to be exactly 29.9212 inHg. That's just the *average* sea-level pressure. So, for instance, if the sea level pressure is currently 30.9 inHg, then all altimeters in the region are going to read 1000 feet below the actual altitude of the airplane.

Those fluctuations are the point of the altimeter corrections provided by AWOS/ASOS/ATIS. By entering the actual sea-level atmospheric pressure into the altimeter, you can correct for those fluctuations and get a more accurate reading of your current altitude.

Comment: @wbeard52 Oops, forgot a zero. Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

The barometric pressure given by the ATIS/AWOS/ASOS is what the atmospheric pressure would be at that lateral position at Mean Sea Level. Any elevation above Mean Sea Level would have a lower atmospheric pressure than the same location at Mean Sea Level. Therefore, an atmospheric pressure reading taken on the surface of an airport/airfield with an elevation of 5000 feet would be much lower than the barometric pressure given by the ATIS/AWOS/ASOS of that same field, signifying the 5000 foot difference between the elevation and Mean Sea Level.

Your pressure sensitive altimeter measures the atmospheric pressure, wherever it is, and converts it to feet above the pressure level set in the Kollsman Window. You dial into the Kollsman Window the barometric pressure at Mean Sea Level to determine your altitude above Mean Sea Level.

In the rare case that the barometric pressure is in an extreme abnormal range, the FAA gives restrictions for flight and adjustment tables for barometric pressure in the FAR/AIM. I have personally only seen this happen in extreme weather, like hurricanes. Most people would not be flying in these conditions.

> **§91.144 Temporary restriction on flight operations during abnormally high barometric pressure conditions.**
> (a) Special flight restrictions. When any information indicates that barometric pressure on the route of flight currently exceeds or will exceed 31 inches of mercury, no person may operate an aircraft or initiate a flight contrary to the requirements established by the Administrator and published in a Notice to Airmen issued under this section.
>
> (b) Waivers. The administrator is authorized to waive any restriction issued under paragraph (a) of this section to permit emergency supply, transport, or medical services to be delivered to isolated communities, where the operation can be conducted with an acceptable level of safety.

> **7–2–2 Procedures**
> The cruising altitude or flight level of aircraft must be maintained by reference to an altimeter which must be set, when operating:
>
> a. Below 18,000 feet MSL.
>
> 1. When the barometric pressure is 31.00 inches Hg. or less. To the current reported altimeter setting of a station along the route and within 100 NM of the aircraft, or if there is no station within this area, the current reported altimeter setting of an appropriate available station. When an aircraft is en route on an instrument flight plan, air traffic controllers will furnish this information to the pilot at least once while the aircraft is in the controllers area of jurisdiction. In the case of an aircraft not equipped with a radio, set to the elevation of the departure airport or use an appropriate altimeter setting available prior to departure.
> 2. When the barometric pressure exceeds 31.00 inches Hg. The following procedures will be placed in effect by NOTAM defining the geographic area affected:
>
> (a) For all aircraft. Set 31.00 inches for en route operations below 18,000 feet MSL. Maintain this setting until beyond the affected area or until reaching final approach segment. At the beginning of the final approach segment, the current altimeter setting will be set, if possible. If not possible, 31.00 inches will remain set throughout the approach. Aircraft on departure or missed approach will set 31.00 inches prior to reaching any mandatory/crossing altitude or 1,500 feet AGL, whichever is lower. (Air traffic control will issue actual altimeter settings and advise pilots to set 31.00 inches in their altimeters for en route operations below 18,000 feet MSL in affected areas.)
>
> (b) During preflight, barometric altimeters must be checked for normal operation to the extent possible.
>
> (c) For aircraft with the capability of setting the current altimeter setting and operating into airports with the capability of measuring the current altimeter setting, no additional restrictions apply.
>
> (d) For aircraft operating VFR, there are no additional restrictions, however, extra diligence in flight planning and in operating in these conditions is essential.
>
> (e) Airports unable to accurately measure barometric pressures above 31.00 inches of Hg. will report the barometric pressure as “missing” or “in excess of 31.00 inches of Hg.” Flight operations to and from those airports are restricted to VFR weather conditions.
>
> (f) For aircraft operating IFR and unable to set the current altimeter setting, the following restrictions apply:
>
> (1) To determine the suitability of departure alternate airports, destination airports, and destination alternate airports, increase ceiling requirements by 100 feet and visibility requirements by 1/4 statute mile for each 1/10 of an inch of Hg., or any portion thereof, over 31.00 inches. These adjusted values are then applied in accordance with the requirements of the applicable operating regulations and operations specifications.
>
> Example: Destination altimeter is 31.28 inches, ILS DH 250 feet (200-1/2). When flight planning, add 300-3/4 to the weather requirements which would become 500-11⁄4.
>
> (2) On approach, 31.00 inches will remain set. Decision height (DH) or minimum descent altitude must be deemed to have been reached when the published altitude is displayed on the altimeter.
>
> Note: Although visibility is normally the limiting factor on an approach, pilots should be aware that when reaching DH the aircraft will be higher than indicated. Using the example above the aircraft would be approximately 300 feet higher.
>
> (3) These restrictions do not apply to authorized Category II and III ILS operations nor do they apply to certificate holders using approved QFE altimetry systems.
>
> (g) The FAA Regional Flight Standards Division Manager of the affected area is authorized to approve temporary waivers to permit emergency resupply or emergency medical service operation.
>
> b. At or above 18,000 feet MSL. To 29.92 inches of mercury (standard setting). The lowest usable flight level is determined by the atmospheric pressure in the area of operation as shown in Table 7-2-1.

> **7–2–4 High Barometric Pressure**
> a. Cold, dry air masses may produce barometric pressures in excess of 31.00 inches of Mercury, and many altimeters do not have an accurate means of being adjusted for settings of these levels. When the altimeter cannot be set to the higher pressure setting, the aircraft actual altitude will be higher than the altimeter indicates.
>
> Reference: AIM, Altimeter Errors, ¶7-2-3
>
> b. When the barometric pressure exceeds 31.00 inches, air traffic controllers will issue the actual altimeter setting, and:
>
> 1. En Route/Arrivals. Advise pilots to remain set on 31.00 inches until reaching the final approach segment.
> 2. Departures. Advise pilots to set 31.00 inches prior to reaching any mandatory/crossing altitude or 1,500 feet, whichever is lower.
>
> c. The altimeter error caused by the high pressure will be in the opposite direction to the error caused by the cold temperature.

> **7–2–5 Low Barometric Pressure**
> When abnormally low barometric pressure conditions occur (below 28.00), flight operations by aircraft unable to set the actual altimeter setting are not recommended.
>
> Note: The true altitude of the aircraft is lower than the indicated altitude if the pilot is unable to set the actual altimeter setting.

Answer (score 0):

IFR approved airplanes require a sensitive altimeter and not just a plain altimeter. When you look at FAA FAR 91.205 you will see a distinction between altimeter for DAY VFR and a sensitive altimeter for IFR.

A sensitive altimeter has a Kollsman window and you can adjust the altitude for the current altimeter setting. Once the altimeter setting is set in, the altimeter must read with ±75 of the current location on the airfield.

You would also be required to adjust the altimeter setting anytime you receive a new weather report from ATC or every 100 NM or so in the absence of such a report.

In areas of really high altimeter settings above 31.00" HG, you should set 31.00" HG even if you altimeter setting can go higher.  Other aircraft may not be able to set the higher altimeter setting.

In areas of really low altimeter settings, it is not recommended to operate an aircraft if you cannot set the correct altimeter setting as you will be lower than indicated on the altimeter.  See AIM 7-2-2.